# In the .NET AssemblyInfo.cs, where to put the license info?

Tags: license-notice, source-code, linked-libraries

In .NET, assemblies have their AssemblyInfo.cs file where one can put general descriptive info about the assembly. **But, where to explicitly put an (open source) license?** I will have a copyright, which is still mine, but how am I supposed to explicitly license via GPL (in this case?)

Here's how I do it for now:

```
// General Information about an assembly is controlled through the following 
// set of attributes. Change these attribute values to modify the information
// associated with an assembly.

[assembly: AssemblyCompany("marcelsuter.ch")]
[assembly: AssemblyProduct("Replayer")]
[assembly: AssemblyCopyright("(c) 2018 by marcelsuter.ch, GPL-v3 licensed")]
[assembly: AssemblyTrademark("")]
[assembly: AssemblyCulture("")]
[assembly: AssemblyVersion("1.6.2")]
```

**This does not seem to fit well, is there a better way to state the license?**

Comment: Are you wrapping your code into a NuGet package? If so, the nuspec file lets you specify a license.

Comment: @PhilipKendall No, this is just getting into a .NET executable (.EXE), which can be downloaded from the github repo.

Answer (score 1):

Are you using the dotnet core? You can use the [PackageLicenseFile](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/csproj#packagelicensefile) and the [PackageLicenseUrl](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/csproj#packagelicenseurl).
Also, related with Assembly information you have this [Assembly Info Properties](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/csproj#assemblyinfo-properties)

All of this information is related to the new `.csproj` structure.